# Is this regex right (eregi to preg_match conversion)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, eregi

I am replacing PHP deprecated functions in my website. I have this code:

```
(eregi("<[^>]*object.*\"?[^>]*>", $secvalue))
```

It is written on the [php.net](http://php.net/) site that it `eregi` should be replaced with preg_match with `i` modifier.

Is this coded right?

```
(preg_match("<[^>]*object.*\"?[^>]*/i>", $secvalue))
```

or should I place `/i` somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_match('/<[^>]*object.*\"?[^>]*>/i', $secvalue)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a forward slash at the beginning to match the closing one:

```
 preg_match('/<[^>]object."?[^>]*>/i', $secvalue);
```